# Spring cache with instance variable and parameter as key

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I am using ehcache for caching the method results. The key has to be a combination of both member object and method's parameter. My class looks something like:

```
Class A {

private B b;

@Cacheable(value="someCache",key="some key based on B and C")
public Result getResult(C c){
......
}
```

I need the key to be based on B and C.
I referred https://code.google.com/p/ehcache-spring-annotations/issues/detail?id=69 but they did not specify how to include the method parameter in the key generation. Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have implemented a custom key generator to solve this. Still I think this can be solved by ehcache without using a custom key generator. But i could not get the answer anywhere. Please see my answer below:

```
@Component
public class Home {

    private Parameter param;

    @Cacheable(cacheName = "homeCache", 
                    keyGenerator = @KeyGenerator(name = "com.myapp.cache.Home.ParamKeyGenerator"))

    public Result getPerson(Person p) {

        //Do something with p
        return result;
    }

    public Parameter getParam() {

        return param;
    }

    public void setParam(Parameter param) {

        this.param = param;
    }

    public static class ParamKeyGenerator implements CacheKeyGenerator<Serializable> {

        public Serializable generateKey(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {

            Object[] obj = methodInvocation.getArguments();
            Home h = (Home) methodInvocation.getThis();

            return this.generateKey(obj[0], h.getParam());
        }

        public Serializable generateKey(Object... data) {

            String key = ((Person) data[0]).getName() + ((Parameter) data[1]).getName();
            System.out.println("generating key: " + key);
            return key;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

you can access the `A` object with `root.target` in the key. e.g.

```
key="#root.target.b.id+'-'+#c.id"
```

Comment: Apologies. I think I gave the spring cache annotation. In ehcache's @Cacheable annotation we dont have 'key'. @Cacheable(cacheName = "homeCache", keyGenerator = .......)

Comment: @cfrick Great. I was looking for this answer. But there is one point to note is the target object should be public.Otherwise you will get error like "EL1008E: Property or field 'B' cannot be found on object of type 'com.test.A' - maybe not public or not valid?"