# Spring Cache with JPA and Specifications

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-cache

I created a REST application using Spring Boot 2.2, Spring Data REST, Hibernate, Spring Redis.

I configured a Redis server where I'd like to cache some queries I do. I already did all optimization I could do, but this is a distributed application and I need to help performance a little bit with centralized cache.
Everything works fine but I don't see how I can create a convenient key when I use Spring repository's method

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "contacts")
@Override
Page findAll(Specification specification, Pageable pageable);
```

This is my Redis configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisCacheConfig extends CachingConfigurerSupport implements CachingConfigurer {
 @Override
    public CacheErrorHandler errorHandler() {
        return new RedisCacheErrorHandler();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean("customKeyGenerator")
    public KeyGenerator keyGenerator() {
        return new CustomKeyGenerator();
    }
}
```

and my key generator:

```
public class CustomKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

    public CustomKeyGenerator() {
    }

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        List<Object> listParams = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(params));
        listParams.add(TenantContext.getCurrentTenantId());//Add tenantId as parameter
        if (StoreContext.getCurrentStoreId() != null)
            listParams.add(StoreContext.getCurrentStoreId());//Add storeId as parameter
        return generateKey(listParams.toArray());
    }

    public static Object generateKey(Object... params) {
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return SimpleKey.EMPTY;
        } else {
            if (params.length == 1) {
                Object param = params[0];
                if (param != null && !param.getClass().isArray()) {
                    return param;
                }
            }

            return new SimpleKey(params);
        }
    }
}
```

When I call `Page findAll(Specification specification, Pageable pageable);`, in my `CustomKeyGenerator` I get parameters but I receive a `SpecificationComposition` (it's a Spring helper class) in place of `Specification`. Its hashcode is different every time I call the method, even if "its content is the same".

Like Pageable that is hashed in the same way every time (`PageRequest` class), I'd like to do the same with `Specification` in order to get advantace of Spring caching mechanism.

[image: During debug,to show the parameter SpecificationComposition]

Do you have any hint to show me the right way?

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019291/spring-cache-with-instance-variable-and-parameter-as-key

Comment: Thanks @MevlütÖzdemir, that's clear. I'm looking for a specific solution: in fact SpecificationComposition is not visible outside the spring package. Not sure there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of struggling I post my personal solution. I don't pretend it is right or a "best practice", so please take it as it is. I'd like to share because, maybe, could help someone with the same need.

This is the key generator:

```
@Log4j2
public class CustomKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {
    private static SpecificationService specificationService;

    public CustomKeyGenerator() {
        specificationService = SpringBeansLoadUtils.getBean(SpecificationService.class);
    }

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {
        //********************************************************************
        // GET GENERICS IN CASE
        // For methods like Page<Document> findAll(Specification specification, Pageable pageable);
        // get the Generics type needed to
        //********************************************************************
        Class returnClass = method.getReturnType();
        Class realClass = null;
        if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(returnClass) || Page.class.isAssignableFrom(returnClass)) {
            Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
            if (returnType instanceof ParameterizedType) {
                ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) returnType;
                Type[] argTypes = paramType.getActualTypeArguments();
                if (argTypes.length > 0) {
                    realClass = (Class) argTypes[0];
                }
            }
        }

        List<Object> listParams = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(params));
        listParams.add(TenantContext.getCurrentTenantId());//Add tenantId as parameter
        if (StoreContext.getCurrentStoreId() != null)
            listParams.add(StoreContext.getCurrentStoreId());//Add storeId as parameter
        return generateKey(realClass, listParams.toArray());
    }

    public static Object generateKey(Class clazz, Object... params) {
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return SimpleKey.EMPTY;
        } else {
            if (params.length == 1) {
                Object param = params[0];
                if (param != null && !param.getClass().isArray()) {
                    return param;
                }
            }

            HashCodeBuilder builder = new HashCodeBuilder();
            for (Object p : params) {
                if (p != null && p.getClass().getSimpleName().contains("SpecificationComposition")) {
                    builder.append(specificationService.hashCode(clazz, (Specification) p));
                } else {
                    builder.append(Arrays.deepHashCode(new Object[]{p}));
                }
            }

            log.info("Hash {}", builder.hashCode());
            return builder.hashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the service that does the job:

```
@Service
@Transactional
@PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
@Log4j2
public class SpecificationService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "optixPU")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    /**
     * Generate an hashCode of the given specification
     *
     * @param clazz
     * @param spec
     * @return
     */
    public Integer hashCode(Class clazz, @Nullable Specification spec) {
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery query = builder.createQuery(clazz);
            Root root = query.from(clazz);

            Predicate predicate = spec.toPredicate(root, query, builder);
            String hash = analyzePredicate(predicate);
            return hash.hashCode();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private String analyzePredicate(Predicate predicate) {
        String stringRepresentation = "";
        for (Expression<Boolean> e : predicate.getExpressions()) {
            if (e instanceof CompoundPredicate) {
                stringRepresentation += analyzePredicate((CompoundPredicate) e);
            } else {
                if (e instanceof InPredicate) {
                    InPredicate inPredicate = (InPredicate) e;
                    for (Object ex : inPredicate.getValues()) {
                        stringRepresentation += analyzeExpression((Expression) ex);
                    }
                } else if (e instanceof LikePredicate) {
                    LikePredicate likePredicate = (LikePredicate) e;
                    String hashExpression = analyzeExpression(likePredicate.getMatchExpression());
                    String hashPattern = analyzeExpression(likePredicate.getPattern());
                    stringRepresentation += hashExpression + hashPattern;
                } else if (e instanceof ComparisonPredicate) {
                    String operator = ((ComparisonPredicate) e).getComparisonOperator().toString();
                    String leftHand = analyzeExpression(((ComparisonPredicate) e).getLeftHandOperand());
                    String rightHand = analyzeExpression(((ComparisonPredicate) e).getRightHandOperand());
                    stringRepresentation += operator + leftHand + rightHand;
                } else {
                    log.warn("Predicate not identified: {}", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return stringRepresentation;
    }

    private String analyzeExpression(Expression expression) {
        if (expression instanceof SingularAttributePath) {
            SingularAttributePath singularAttributePath = (SingularAttributePath) expression;
            return singularAttributePath.getAttribute().getName();
        } else if (expression instanceof LikeExpression) {
            LiteralExpression likeExpression = (LiteralExpression) expression;
            return likeExpression.getLiteral().toString();
        }
        if (expression instanceof LiteralExpression) {
            return ((LiteralExpression) expression).getLiteral().toString();
        } else if (expression instanceof ConcatExpression) {
            ConcatExpression concatExpression = (ConcatExpression) expression;
            String code1 = analyzeExpression(concatExpression.getString1());
            String code2 = analyzeExpression(concatExpression.getString2());
            return code1 + code2;
        } else {
            log.warn("Expression {} not identified", expression);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

The service doesn't handle all `Predicate`/`Expression` cases, but it warns when it doesn't.

Basically the idea is to create a `Predicate` from the `Specification` and analyze it to generate a string of its values and then create an hashCode.

With this code the resulting key seems stable and now I'm able to cache my Query like  `Page findAll(Specification specification, Pageable pageable);`